# How to know which variable value is set for union?

Tags: c, logic, unions

I am working on optimization of a project. It contains a struct of an options in which user can select a single option at a time. In addition to the option, we also use a flag variable to check which option value is set for this record.
     In order to make it memory efficient I want to convert struct  into a union. But How do I know that which variable value is set in union. Because there is no restriction in union to fetch a value of a variable even which is not set.

```
 struct options{
     int basicPay;
     int lumsumPay;
     int mothlyPay;
     int weeklyPay;
     int dailyPay;
     int anualPay;

     int payType;   // Flag variable to check which option is selected
 };

union OptimizeOptions{
    int basicPay;
    int lumsumPay;
    int mothlyPay;
    int weeklyPay;
    int dailyPay;
    int anualPay;

    int payType;   // Confuse at here
 };
```

Comment: @user3121023 is right -- the only time you need a union is when one or more of the members have different types.  Also spelling: `lumpsumPay`, `monthlyPay` and `annualPay`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried a `union` inside of a `struct`? Let’s see the following example equivalent:

```
union options{
  int basicPay;
  int lumsumPay;
  int mothlyPay;
  int weeklyPay;
  int dailyPay;
  int anualPay;
};

struct record{
  union options op;   // Options union
  int payType;   // Flag variable to check which option is selected
}
```

The union (`options`) will reserve memory for its largest variable and you can set its value and your structure (record) will keep track of that union memory block and the `payType` flag value could be set which will tell your program to fetch the perticular variable of the union.

Comment: `union options *op` doesn't need to be a pointer and would make usage of `struct record` easier if it was `union options op` instead.

Comment: If all union options are of the same type `int` do you really need the union? struct with two `int`s should be enough.

Answer (score 21):

Unions suffers from a problem that there is no easy way to know which member of a union was last changed. In order to keep track of this information, you can embed `union` inside a structure that has one another member (called "*tag field*" or "*discriminant*"). The purpose of tag field is to remind which member is changed/updated. You can try this:

```
typedef struct{
       int payType;      // Tag field 

       union{
           int basicPay;
           int lumsumPay;
           int mothlyPay;
           int weeklyPay;
           int dailyPay;
           int anualPay;
      }OptimizeOptions;

}Options;
```

But, there is no need to write six separate members for union in your case as all are of `int` type. Therefore it can be reduced to

```
typedef struct{
    enum{BASIC_PAY, LUMSUM_PAY, MONTHLU_PAY, WEEKLY_PAY, DAILY_PAY, ANNUAL_PAY} payType; 
    int pay;
}Options;
```

---

Lets understand the *use of tag field* with a simple example. Suppose we want an array which can store `int` and `double` type data. This would become possible by using `union`. So, first define a union type which will store either `int` or `double`.

```
typedef union {
      int i;
      double d;
} Num;
```

Next we have to create an array whose elements are `Num` type

```
Num num_arr[100];
```

Now, suppose we want to assign element `0` of the `num_arr` to store `25`, while element `1` stores `3.147`. This can be done as

```
num_arr[0].i = 25;
num_arr[1].d = 3.147;
```

Now suppose that we have to write a function which will print the `num_arr` elements. The function would be like this:

```
void print_num(Num n)
{
     if(n contains integer)
         printf("%d", n.i);
     else
         printf("%f", n.d);
}
```

Wait! How could `print_num` will decide whether `n` contains an integer or `double`?

This will be done by using the tag field:

```
typedef struct{
    enum{INT, DOUBLE} kind;        //Tag field
    union{
       int i;
       double d;
    }u;
}Num;
```

So, each time a value is assigned to a member of `u`, `kind` *must*<sup>**1**</sup> be set to either `INT` or `DOUBLE` to remind that what type we actually stored. For example:

```
n.u.i = 100;
n.kind = INT;
```

The `print_num` function would be like this:

```
void print_num(Num n)
{
     if(n.kind == INT)
         printf("%d", n.i);
     else
         printf("%f", n.d);
}
```

---

<sub>**1**: It is programmer's responsibility to update the tag field with each assignment to the member of `union`. Forgetting to do so will lead to bug, as pointed in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297188/how-to-know-which-variable-value-is-set-for-union/26297219?noredirect=1#comment41277810_26297219) by @  [j_random_hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47984/j-random-hacker).</sub>

Comment: You forgot to declare a _field_ of type `union OptimizeOptions` -- currently you're just declaring the union type itself, but no field of that type.

Comment: I suggest changing "can" to "must" in "`kind` will be set to either `INT` or `DOUBLE`", to make it clear that this is something the programmer must do themselves; forgetting to do it will cause bugs.

Comment: @j_random_hacker; Agreed. Updated the answer.

Comment: It might be even better to put `enum` member, e.g. `enum {INT, DOUBLE} kind;` instead (implicitely with zero and one respectively), as in that way you can place possible choices directly into `struct` template and consequently not as some "loose" object-like macros beside it.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski; First I thought the same. Latter I thought that OP may will confuse by seeing `enum` and `union` together inside a `struct` and may will fail to digest. That's why I used macro, but agreed with using `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

There is now `std::variant` that wraps up this common functionality.

```
std::variant<int, float> x;
x = 42;
bool is_x_an_int = std::holds_alternative<int>(x); // YES
bool is_x_a_float = std::holds_alternative<float>(x); // NO
int value_of_x = std::get<int>(x); // 42
int an_error = std::get<float>(x); // exception
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant.